# Invalid column name when inserting a row to sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

**Hi
I have a sql table with this defenition:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
[Id]             INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[TelegramId]     BIGINT       NULL,
[Username]       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[FName]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[LName]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Gender]         BIT          NOT NULL,
[WantedGender]   BIT          NOT NULL,
[Age]            INT          NOT NULL,
[WantedAgeRange] INT          NOT NULL,
[TakenLike]      BIGINT       NOT NULL,
[Hot]            BIT          NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

**and when I try to add a row to this table with this code:**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Table](TelegramId, UserName, FName, LName, Gender, WantedGender, Age, WantedAgeRange, TakenLikes, Hot)" +
                    " VALUES (@telID, @username, @fname, @lname, @gender, @wgender, @age, @wage, @tlikes, @hot)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telID", temp.TelegramId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", temp.UserName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", temp.FName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", temp.LName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", temp.Gender);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wgender", temp.WantedGender);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", temp.Age);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wage", temp.WantedAgeRange);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tlikes", "0");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hot", "0");
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    bot.SendTextMessage(53654050, "added to Table...");

                }
            }
```

**but I get this error:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Gender'.
>   Invalid column name 'WantedGender'.
>   Invalid column name 'Age'.
>   Invalid column name 'WantedAgeRange'.
>   Invalid column name 'TakenLikes'.
>   Invalid column name 'Hot'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at...

**and the temp is a object from a class with these items:**

```
long TelegramId, TakenLikes;
string UserName, FName, LName;
int Age, WantedAgeRange, Gender, WantedGender, Hot;
```

**How can I fix this error?
thank you**

Comment: Make sure your SqlConnection is pointed to the database same as the database where `[dbo].[Table]` is created..

Comment: use a profiler to see exact what is send to your database

Comment: check ur connection string

Comment: go to Sql Server Configuration management->SQL Server network config->protocols for 'servername' and check named pipes is enabled.

Comment: my connection string is OK because I can read the data from Table in this database. I just get error when I want to insert row

Comment: what tool in performance profiler should I use to see this? @GuidoG

Comment: Lose the string literal **@**

Comment: that was disable, I made it enable, restarted the service but the error still exists @Rohit Poudel

Comment: did you restart the system @Lionking89

Comment: Just to be sure, when you reaad the data from the table to the datatable are you getting values for gender or the property is null?

Comment: @Lionking89 not the performance profiler, but the sql profiler that shows every call to your database

Comment: Are there any triggers on your table?

Comment: probably not the only problem but you have in your table design a column named TakenLike and your query is using TakenLike**s**

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Use a multi-line string to define the query (or `StringBuilder`).
2. Escape your table fields.

   ```
   string query = @"INSERT INTO [Table]([TelegramId], [UserName], [FName], [LName], [Gender], [WantedGender], [Age], [WantedAgeRange], [TakenLikes], [Hot])
                    VALUES (@telID, @username, @fname, @lname, @gender, @wgender, @age, @wage, @tlikes, @hot)";


   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con) ...
   ```

> Note: I strongly recommend creating a stored procedure to do this. And invoking it from ADO.NET

I also suspect something might be amuck with the chosen table name of `Table`. Is it possible to rename this, and to also fully qualify it in your query? Something like `[dbo].[User]`?

Barring this, I would recommend copying the query text and running directly in SSMS. It perhaps will give you a more clear error and will server useful as a debugging step.

Comment: I defined query with stringbuilder and used '[' and ']' befor and after columns names but error showed again

Comment: @Lionking89 see answer.